# In BigQuery How to subset a dataset using distinct column values from other data set

Tags: google-bigquery, subset

I have two data sets:

Data set A:
Which has got ID and Code value for customers.

Data set B:
Has got only code values.

How can I subset data set A so that only code values from B will get selected in Bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use exists:

```
select * 
from dataset.setA a
where exists (select 1 from dataset.setB b where a.code = b.code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try left out join

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.setB a left outer join dataset.setA b on a.code = b.code
WHERE b.code is null
```

It will give only records present in dataset.setB, it will ignore all matching records & records not present in dataset.setB but present in dataset.setA.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from dataset.setA
where code in (select code from dataset.setB)
```